# How to cyclically pass variables in selector in WebDriverSampler in JMeter?

Tags: variables, xpath, jmeter, webdriver, cycle

I have a set of timeslots I need to click in JMeter script cyclically.

For 1st timeslot with timeslot id=1 the code in WebDriver Sampler is:

> // select timeslot:

> wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("//div[@id='timeslot1']")));

> var Timeslot =
> WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//div[@id='timeslot1']"));

> Timeslot.click();

How is it possible to pass a value from a set of variables instead of specific selector ("//div[@id='timeslot1']")?

A set of variables looks like:

> //div[@id='timeslot1']

> //div[@id='timeslot2']

> //div[@id='timeslot3']

> //div[@id='timeslot4']

> //div[@id='timeslot5']

...

> //div[@id='timeslotN']

N - also is a variable, how much iterations should be performed with timeslots.

What is the best way to perform many requests cyclically with passing variables instead of selectors?

**UPD.**
I tried following ways:

1)

wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath(WDS.vars.get('//div[@id='timeslot'+N]'))));

var Underwriter_Timeslot = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath(WDS.vars.get('//div[@id='timeslot'+N]')));

(N - external variable from Loop controller, sending request sequentially with N from 1 to 10).

But, in that case I have an error that xpath is null.

2)

var XPath_Timeslot_Number = WDS.vars.get('//div[@id='timeslot'' + WDS.vars.get('N')]);
WDS.vars.put('XPath_Timeslot_Number', XPath_Timeslot_Number);
WDS.log.info('XPath_Timeslot_Number is: ' + XPath_Timeslot_Number);

wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("WDS.vars.get('XPath_Timeslot_Number')")));
var Timeslot = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("WDS.vars.get('XPath_Timeslot_Number')"));
Timeslot.click();

Any insights, what is the correct option to get this sequential generation of timeslot numbers in xpath?

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand for getting the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value from the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) is:

```
var myVar = WDS.vars.get('myVar')
```

where `WDS.vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the documentation for all possible functions

So you can do something like:

```
var i = 0
var n = parseInt(WDS.vars.get('N'))
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath(WDS.vars.get('some_prefix' + n));
}
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: thank you. 
I tried following:

wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath(WDS.vars.get('//div[@id='timeslot'+N]'))));

var Underwriter_Timeslot = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath(WDS.vars.get('//div[@id='timeslot'+N]')));

(N - external variable from Loop controller, sending request sequentially with N from 1 to 10).

But not sure at syntax if I have null xpath. What I'm missing?...